# R: Recreate table from unique() and table()

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a dataframe with a column of about 300k records, of which 7k are unique.
I need to perform heavy operations on the table, however the frequency of the records matters.
My idea is to perform the operations on the unique table and then to mulitply the result by the frequency of the repeated terms.

```
col<-(c('a','f','d','s','a','d','s','a'))
rep<-data.frame(col)
a<-as.data.frame(table(rep))
```

Rep:

```
  col
1   a
2   f
3   d
4   s
5   a
6   d
7   s
8   a
```

Freq. table:
[image: frequency table]

Unique values:

```
1   a
2   f
3   d
4   s
```

Is there any way to do this without a loop?

The performance is next to terrible for this many rows... Do you have any sugestion for this?

Thanks,
Miguel

Comment: Wait, what?  You just did it.  Or do you just want `unique(rep)`? Maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: I want to get the 300k columns, after having done the intensive operations on the unique columns... I just got the frequency of the duplicated terms...  Usually people want to remove duplicates. I need to create them. The degree of 'duplicatedness' is given by the frequency table

Comment: yep - rows. My mistake.

Comment: just repeat the rows based on the table? `unique(rep)[rep(match(a$rep, unique(rep)$col), a$Freq), , drop = FALSE]`

Comment: thanks rawr ! that it the spot!